# Complex eigenvalue of a linear transformation on a real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I think the following definition of an eigenvalue of a linear map is standard.

**Definition**: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$. An eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a linear transformation $f \colon V \to V$ is a scalar in $F$ such that $f(v) = \lambda v$ for some nonzero $v \in V$.

If we take this definition and consider the case $F = \mathbb{R}$, an eigenvalue of $f$ must be a real number.

At the same time, an eigenvalue of a real matrix $A$ is usually allowed to be a complex number and can be imaginary. For example, the fact that any eigenvalue of a (real) symmetric matrix is real is not a direct consequence of the definition but a claim that must be proven.

**Question 1**: If we consider a complex eigenvalue of an $n \times n$ real matrix $A$, do we assume that $A$ is a linear transformation on $\mathbb{C}^n$ (not $\mathbb{R^n}$)?

**Question 2**: If we take the above **Definition**, does a symmetric (self-adjoint) transformation $f$ on a real vector space $V$ with some inner product have by definition only real eigenvalues?
It can be proved that, however, if we endow $V$ with some basis and take a corresponding representation matrix $A$ of $f$, all eigenvalues (allowing complex numbers) of $A$ are real. Does such a discussion (i.e., allowing a possibility of imaginary eigenvalues of $f$ and then excluding them) make sense? But if so, what is a complex (possibly imaginary) eigenvalue of a general linear map $f$ on a real vector space?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Thank you for your reasonable answer. I feel people usually consider the eigenvalues of a real matrix within the complex field without saying anything. But probably in such a case, we should (implicitly or explicitly) regard the matrix as an endomorphism of a complex vector space.

Comment: @GEdgar: Thank you for pointing out the error in the question. I edited it (added the word "nonzero").

Comment: Any real vector space $V$ has a "complexification": $V^* = V\times V$ endowed with the complex scalar multiplication $(x + iy)(u, v) \mapsto (xu - yv, xv + yu)$. If $V$ has an inner product, it induces an inner product on $V^*: (u,v)\cdot (u',v') = u\cdot u' - v\cdot v' +i(u\cdot v' + v\cdot u')$. A transformation $f : V \to V$ induces an extension to the complexification: $f(u,v) = (fu, fv)$. This extension is now a transformation on a complex vector space and can have complex eigenvalues. If the original $f$ is symmetric, the complex $f$ is self-adjoint, and its eigenvalues are real.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Thank you for the excellent explanation. It nicely explains the correspondence between the real matrix space and general real vector space. From my understanding, when we think about complex eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ real matrix, we (possibly implicitly) consider such a complexification of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes, but of course, the complexification of $\Bbb R^n$ is just $\Bbb C^n$. The concept of complexification was invented to show how linear operators on arbitrary finite dimensional real vector spaces could naturally have complex eigenvalues.